# warpPerspective inverse transformation for a point in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, transformation

In my project, I get points in a larger image of a territory I want to crop, I transform it using `perspectiveTransform` and `warpPerspective` methods and retrieve a new image, transform it to a rectangle. In that new image I find specific points (x,y) and want to transform them backwards to original image, relatively to its perspective. For that purpose I used the same `warpPerpective` with the same arguments, but with a flag `WARP_INVERSE_MAP`. However, it returns me a large array of arrays of zeros.

**How can I make inverted transformation not for an image, but for a point (in python)?**

This is the code I use:

```
p = (123, 234)
p_array = np.array([[p[0], p[1]]], dtype=np.float32)
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(points, output_points)
transformed_points = cv2.warpPerspective(p_array, matrix, table_image_size, cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
```

Where:

*points*- 4 points which are to be cropped from an original image,

*output_points*- 4 points of where cropped image has to be placed into new image

*table_image_size*- horizontal and vertical size of an image

These parameters are in forward transformation and in this inverse transformation are identical, the only difference is that instead of an image to crop from I insert *p_array* in `warpPerspective` method.

Answer (score 2):

From warpPerspective [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87):

> **dsize:**     size of the output image.

use `transformed_points = cv2.warpPerspective(p_array, matrix, (2,1), cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)`

Comment: Thanks. However, it still returned me an array of zeros. I figured out that warpPerspective is unsuitable for point transformations and solved my problem with perspectiveTransform method.

Comment: @DainiusŠaltenis Can you send me the link how you achieved this? I also need to know where a point moves after perspective transform. Thanks in advance!